# Available IDC trace data/cluster data

Tags: bigdata

I am interested in analyzing the workload and identifying bottle-neck in Internet Data Center (IDC). Currently, I am aware of the two trace data: Google's data from 2011 and Alibaba's trace data 2017 and 2018.

I was wondering if there are more related data that is not as popular as Google or Alibaba but still is available.

Thank you. (Sorry, my tag is not appropriate but I was not able to get anything better than that).